# Formulas `A1:A` and `A1:Z` give invalid name error in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, office365

Selecting a range of definite size (e.g. `A1:A2`) works just fine, but selecting a range to the last row does not. If relevant, I am using Office 365.

[image: Error in formula]

Comment: Excel does not accept open ended range references like `A1:A` .  One must state the ending row or full column reference.

Comment: @ScottCraner it accepts that in array formulas

Answer (score 2):

You can do open references like A:A or 1:1 but cannot mix and match the fixed and open references. To reference the last non-blank cell:

```
=INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))
```

Or the whole non-blank range:

```
=A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the C1:C to C:C, it will work for you.